# Total from column changes weekly vba

Tags: excel, vba, automation, range

UPDATE: 
Got a new issue with a formula, can't quite get it to work because of text in the formula, the formula (as taken from excel) should be,

```
=IF(D2<=0,"No Sales Price",E2/D2)
```

I have tried as many combinations as I can think of but the "no sales price" is causing an issue with the quotation marks. My current code is

```
For i = 2 To LastRowG   
Range("Q" & i).Formula = "=IF(D" & i & "<=0," & "(No Sales Price)",  & "(E" & i & "/D" & i & "))"    
Next i
```

have had a look around but been unable to see any resolutions to the problem, any enlightenment will be met with the greatest appreciation

EDIT:This was fixed by inserting the following lines;

```
For i = 2 To LastRowG  
Range("Q" & i).Formula = "=IF(D" & i & "<=0," & Chr(34) & "No Sales Price" & Chr(34) & "," & "E" & i & "/" & "D" & i & ")"
Next i
```

The Chr(34) inserts the ASCII character appertaining to that number which just so happens to be ". The program doesn't read it as having typed in the quote marks and continues to read the line of code correctly but then places the "no sales price" correctly in the formula.

It will output the line as the formula is intended to be and the Chr(34) is like writing ""No Sales Price"" without the inevitable "expected end of statement" error

Comment: If you record the macro, you have a fixed range correct? But what if you add a check for the last row in C and set your range C1:C(last row) and get the sum of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggested will result in something like this:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Cells(LastRow + 1, 3).Formula = "=SUM(C1:C" & LastRow & ")"
```

**Extra 1**

Is it possible to use this formula to enter the word Total in the cell to the left?

```
Range("B" & LastRow + 1) = "Total"
```

**Extra 2**

One more just to push my luck, how about copying a formula all the way down a column the the last cell? `=G2*57.5 copied until the last row in I`

```
LastRowG = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowG
    Range("I" & i).Value = "=G" & i & "*57.5"
Next i
```

Comment: @JamesDev, I found this SUM function here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960695/excel-vba-sum-up-a-column

Comment: @JamesDev, it wasn't a copy/paste solution at first, try now please. The use of `Range("C1:C" & LastRow)` in the second line was to show you what your range would be for the `SUM`.

Comment: @JamesDev, checked what was wrong and double checked and verified my solution!

Comment: You absolute hero among men. There is no end to the love I have for you right now

Comment: Is it possible to use this formula to enter the word Total in the cell to the left?

Comment: @JamesDev, add this: `Range("B" & LastRow + 1) = "Total"`

Comment: You pro, one more just to push my luck, how about copying a formula all the way down a column the the last cell?

Comment: @JamesDev, let me try something and I'll edit my original answer and how do you know what's the last row? Is that based on column C and which formula do you want?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18859/discussion-between-t-thielemans-and-jamesdev)

Comment: all columns are the same length, to help with your solution I have a formula in "I2" that needs to copy down to the last used row in that column

Comment: Got a new issue with a formula, can't quite get it to work because of text in the formula, the formula (as taken from excel) should be, =IF(D2<=0,"No Sales Price",E2/D2).............I have tried as many combinations as I can think of but the "no sales price" is causing an issue with the quotation marks. My current code is........................................For i = 2 To LastRowG
Range("Q" & i).Formula = "=IF(D" & i & "<=0," & "(No Sales Price"), " & "(E" & i & "/D" & i & "))"
Next i

Comment: `"(No Sales Price"),"` is giving me the error, so deleting the `"` inside the () should solve it. `"(No Sales Price),"`