# sum of particular cells of a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro where I need sum of a range of cells in a column. But that is a variable with every run. The range of cells will vary every time I will run the macro.I tried using the answer on this link [Excel VBA - Sum up a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960695/excel-vba-sum-up-a-column)

But its not working for my code.

```
first_line = ws.Cells(i, k).Value
last_line = ws. cells(i + 3, k).Value
sum_each_col = "=SUM(first_line, j:last_lin - 1, j)"
ws.cells(last_line, j) = sum_each_col
```

j is the column no.
It is not working. I m sure I have misunderstood something in the code. Request you to please have a look at it once as I am just a beginner on this.

Comment: `worksheetfunction.sum`

Comment: To add a variable into a string, you need to close the string first:  `MsgBox "Start at row " & first_line & " and end at line " & last_lin -1` should give you some clues.  (Pay attention to the colour-coding ☺)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use this

```
With ws
    first_line = .Cells(i, k).Value
    last_line = .Cells(i + 3, k).Value
    .Cells(last_line, j) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range(.Cells(first_line, j), .Cells(last_line - 1, j)))
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you wan to find sum of first three rows in a column. Then in the fourth row of that column you have to get the sum. VBA code will be like below for the fourth row of that column.

```
ws.cells(4,j) = "=SUM(R[-3]C:R[-1]C)"
```